# When route change the getter not recalculate which cause to wrong data

Tags: angular, ngrx

I want to select from the store the productId from the route.

so I have getter function in my component:

```
get productId() {
 const x = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('productId');
 console.log({ x });
 return x;
}

product$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectProductById, { productId: this.productId }));
```

The problem is when I navigate to another product, the `product$` doesn't change. because the getter is not recalculate. and the `selectProductById` not recalculate either.

What can I do to get the product$ when the route change?

Comment: Did you try something  `product$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectProductById, { productId: this.route.snapshot.params['productId'] }));` in ngOnInit lifeCycle Hook?

Answer (score 1):

Snapshot won’t get updated if we try to reload the current route with different route parameter. 
In your case you should use `subscribe` instead of `snapshot`:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    const productId = params['productId'];
    product$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectProductById, { productId: productId}));
});
```

More explanation:
https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information

Comment: I prefer to not use subscribe, maybe a combine of two observers. like withLatestfrom or pass the observable to the selector.

Comment: U should always unsubscribe from observables in onDestroy to prevent memory leaks.